# Console and Cygwin integration

Tags: cygwin, console

I've installed new Cygwin: 1.7 and couldn't create a [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)! tab for Cygwin like before. Is there anybody there who has successfully used Cygwin inside Console?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Cygwin in ConsolePortable. Sure, you can do it without a cygwin.bat file; just put **/path/to/cygwin/bin/bash --login -i** as your shell. There is a lot more flexibility if you use a bat file to launch it, though; for example, you can specify a home directory outside the Cygwin folder. Assumptions:

```
doc/unix/.bashrc    
dev/ConsolePortable/Data/Settings/console.xml
dev/ConsolePortable/console.exe
dev/cygwin/cygwin.bat
```

Edit ConsolePortable/Data/Settings/console.xml:

```
<settings>
<!-- console.xml -->
    <console shell="..\cygwin\cygwin.bat" init_dir="..\cygwin" >
<!-- ... etc ... -->
</settings>
```

Edit cygwin.bat:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL
set SHELL=/bin/bash
REM -> you can set home here if you don't want /cygwin/home/username, e.g. HOME=%~dp0..\..\doc\unix
bin\bash --login -i
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use Cygwin with Console2. In settings, create a tab with the following shell value:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i`
```

That's it (assuming you installed Cygwin to the default directory, otherwise change the path to `bash.exe` accordingly).

Personally, I've gone one step further and set a default directory for Cygwin to start in, by using this shell value:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Stuff/; exec /bin/bash"
```

You'd need to alter the `/cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Stuff/` part to something appropriate for your file system.